# Como puedo guardar un arraylist en un txt y luego cargarlo?

Tags: java, netbeans, poo

como puedo guardar un arraylist en un txt y ese arreglo guardado leerlo cuando vuelva a abrir el programa, basicamente lo que necesito es que los datos que voy a meter en un jtable se guarden al cerrar la ventana y cuando vuelva abrir se carguen los datos al arraylist para que sean mostrados en el jtable

Así estoy guardando:

```
public void guardarTxt() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("Datos/Encuestados.txt");  
        try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fout)) {
            out.writeObject(Encuestados);
        }
    }
```

Pero no sabria como leerlo y cargarlos al arraylist, Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como muestran en la doc del [ObjectInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) es muy sencillo. Literalmente solo tienes que hacer el proceso inverso al que estas haciendo.

Primero obtienes el inputStream del archivo, despues obtienes el valor del objeto almacenado en el archivo utilizando el método `readObject()` y por ultimo casteas este valor a tipo de objeto que quieras.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Datos/Encuestados.txt");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

encuestados = (List<Encuestado>) ois.readObject();

ois.close();
```

Ademas ten en cuenta que el archivo que estas creando no es un archivo de texto, es un archivo binario. Si lo abres con un editor de texto te saldrán un montón de símbolos raros.

Answer (score -1):

Primero optaría por ir uno a uno los elementos de la lista y le añadiría un delimitador. Estoy suponiendo de que el listado `Encuestados` es String.

```
Private static String DELIMITADOR=";";    

public void guardarTxt() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("Datos/Encuestados.txt");  
    for(int i=0;i<Encuestados.size();i++)
    {
       if(i==Encuestados.size()-1)
       {
          fout.write(Encuestados.get(i));
       }
       else
       {
          fout.write(Encuestados.get(i)+DELIMITADOR);
       }
    }
}
```

Lo siguiente es el reader de el fichero

```
public void leerTxt() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("Datos/Encuestados.txt");
    String fileText="";

    //Leemos byte a byte
    int i;
    while((i=fr.read()) != -1)
    {
        fileText+=(char)i;
    }

    //Separamos el string por el delimitador y sobrescribimos la lista
    Encuestados= new ArrayList(fileText.split(DELIMITADOR));

}
```

[Aquí](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-reading-text-file-java/) tienes mas formas de leer ficheros.

Por ultimo, un consejo de convenciones de nombres, las variables empiezan por minúscula. Por lo que tu listado debería de llamarse `encuestados`.

Comment: El usuario busca la lectura como objeto, no como Strings por lo que la respuesta no le vale. Aparte, como haya `;` en los textos ya no le funcionaría.